# MySQL Cast or Convert

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Using MySQL, I'm trying to get Cast or Convert to work. Which should I use and how would I get it to work. Currently here is my schema

```
Table: monies
colomns: 
amount(decimal[10,2])
percentage(decimal[2,2])
```

Attempted sql:

```
SELECT CONVERT((amount * percentage), DECIMAL(100,2)) FROM user_earnings;
```

Thanks,

Comment: More recent versions of MySQL limit the precision to 65.  However, it doesn't make a difference which of the two functions you use.

Comment: out of curiosity, what happens if you don't convert anything?

Comment: Why are you converting this? Both values are in decimal?

Comment: I should have been specific, sorry. i need to cut off at the nearest hundredth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So why not just this :

```
SELECT round((amount * percentage),2) FROM monies;
```

EDIT :

```
SELECT format((amount * percentage),2) FROM monies;
```

Comment: what if amount = 50.00 and percentage = 0.50. The result is 25.0 (I need the hundredth, even if it's just 0)

Comment: Although, I agree. Round is probably safer, if only it could force out two decimal places.

Comment: This was actually the right answer. It was my code that was trimming it at the tenth number.

Answer (score 2):

CAST and CONVERT do the same thing but it just like CONVERT gives more options

Also check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html).

Comment: cast is part of the SQL standard, while convert is not